# Dateconvert into xx.xx.xxxx

Tags: javascript, html, date, datetime

```
Mon Apr 20 00:00:00 CEST 2015
```

How can I convert this to 20.04.2015 with Javascript?

Ive updated the Backend in a Webclient, before this, the following function run perfectly, but jet is another datetime convert..
Before the Update the Datetime was an SQL Date like this 2015-04-12T00:00:00.000

```
<script>
       var php = '{{SYSDATE}}';
       var i = php.slice(0,10).split('-');
       var sysdate = i[2]+'.'+i[1]+'.'+i[0];
</script>
```

Here is the HTML for this function:

```
 <span class="sysdatestamp"><script type="text/javascript">document.write(sysdate)</script></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use php date_format function:

```
date_format ( date_create('2015-04-12T00:00:00.000') , 'd.m.Y' );
```

[PHP: date_format - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-format.php)